# to add event listener for getting video duration in run time in videojs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-video, video.js

I want to monitor the video duration as the video plays using any event listener. I am using `videojs` for video playback.

I came across events like `play`, `myplayer.isPaused` but they fire only once. 
`myplayer` is the video element for `videojs`. 
Now upon further research i got an event named  `on`. 
So here goes the code :

```
myPlayer.on("play", myfun);

  function myfun() {
    console.log("myPlayer.currentTime()");
    console.log(myPlayer.currentTime());
    myfun();
  }
```

Here is what i expected that it will give me `currentTime` as you can see i am calling `myfun` recursively.
But this function is getting called a million times but only gives me the starting time which is `0`.

I even tried to put `myPlayer.currentTime()` in `setInterval`, but this method is not trustworthy and ofcourse not a good idea.

I used native javascript eventlisteners but they are not likely to be useful.

So any help to attach event listener for the videoplayback sothat i would get the play duration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `play` event is fired only when playback starts. If you want to monitor progress into the video then the correct event is [timeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate). Here is an example:

```
myPlayer.on("timeupdate", myfun);

function myfun() {
    console.log("myPlayer.currentTime()", myPlayer.currentTime());
}
```